# Azure Managed Data Disk Not Encrypting

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-storage, azure-cli

I have been following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-windows) to encrypt a data disk on a VM. I am running the following command:

```
az vm encryption enable --resource-group "RGName" --name "VMName" --disk-encryption-keyvault "KVName" --volume-type "ALL"
```

The OS Disk IS encrypted, but the data disk is not. I have also tried running the same command above just specifying the volume-type as Data. I am not sure why the disk is not encrypting. When I run the command, it looks like it is running, the page says updating in ARM, but when all is said and done, it is not encrypted.

Comment: how long did you wait? it might take quite some time with regular disks, try with a small ssd data disk (like 30 gb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.  The disk in question was attached to a VM but not mounted and formatted.  Once I mounted and formatted the drive, I was able to encrypt it.